# How to send mail to specified email address using gmail smtp details

Tags: c#, smtp, sendmail

On contact us page fields are name, email address and message.

That details send to specified mail address with entered mail address in the form.

Is it possible with gmail smtp details.

smtp details as below

```
Host: smtp.gmail.com
Username: *****@gmail.com
Password: ********
Port: 25
```

Comment: You are essentially asking how to spoof senders through Gmail, which I expect falls outside its terms of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gmail doesn't allow you to change the FROM to something different than your gmail account**.

It doesn't matter what you use, they over-write it, before they relay it on. This prevent spamming/spoofing.